# Как правильно указать top координаты

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```js
function showTooltipCard(id_profile, position, target) {
  var tooltip_card = ge("tooltip_card");
  var client_x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var client_y = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var left, top;

  var card_header = ge("card_header");
  var card_icon = ge("card_icon");
  var card_user_name = ge("card_user_name");
  var url = "/?act=card";
  ajax.post({
    url: url,
    data: "user_id=" + id_profile,
    callback: function(data) {
      var response = JSON.parse(data);
      if (response.error) {
        Box.info("Ошибка", response.error.msg);
        return;
      }
      card_header.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + response.card.backgroundHeader + ")";
      card_icon.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + response.card.backgroundIcon + ")";
      card_user_name.innerHTML = response.card.userName;
      card_user_name.href = "/id" + id_profile;

      tooltip_card.classList.remove("none");

      /**
      * здесь top координаты
      */
 
      left = position['left'] + (target.offsetWidth - tooltip_card.offsetWidth) / 2;

      tooltip_card.style.left = left + "px";
      tooltip_card.style.top = top + "px";

      console.log("position Y " + position['y']);
      console.log("client Y " + client_y);
      console.log("offsetHeight " + tooltip_card.offsetHeight);
      console.log("---------------------------------------------");
    }
  });
}
```

2-ой параметр `position` принимает объект:

```
var object = {
  "left": getPositionCursorWindow(self).left, //el.getBoundingClientRect()
  "top": getPositionCursorWindow(self).top, 
  "x": getPositionCursor(self).x, //координаты курсора 
  "y": getPositionCursor(self).y
};
```

3 параметр - `target` - основной элемент, который получил событие(над которым должен появиться тултип - `tooltip_card`)

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как правильно указать `top` координаты, чтобы тултип показывался в пределах экрана и при скролле и без него.

Answer (score 0):

top нужно высчитывать так же как и left только используя offsetHeight

Comment: у меня проблема не с высчитыванием offsetHeight, а с сохранением видимости тултипа при скролле, учитывая границы экрана

Comment: если поставить position fixed, при скролее он будет на месте, либо подписаться на событие onScroll, и изменять высоту в ручную, если я правильно понял